# Operational Model schema

Tags: sql, database, database-design, schema

I was assigned a task to design a database schema using operational model, but unfortunately unable to get any information on what exactly the operational model mean.

I worked extensively on Star and snowflake schemas but management doesn't require these schema designs and stressing me to create a operational model.

If anyone can give some insight on what operational model and how can I get some knowledge would be great help.

Comment: What do you mean by "operational model"? It is not a standard term. What does "management" say it means?

Comment: @philipxy Management means 'Manager who assigns the work to me' and I was told to create a `Operational Model`, If its not a standard term then what would be it referred to according to my requirement?

Comment: There's nothing in your question that says what is meant by it and it's not a standard term so how do you exect us to know? You'd have to ask the person who used it what they meant by it. What else did they say exactly? Maybe they meant "operating model", but that isn't a database term & it's generic. From "I was assigned a task to design a database schema using [an?] operational model" it seems like maybe you mean "using the relational model".  Presumably you know what they meant by now & can tell us.

Comment: @philipxy I ended up using combination of OLAP and OLTP as explained in below question and it worked, not sure if it is operating model or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operational Model is a model which would help in daily operations and not just getting statistics about the data.

The management is looking for a daily Transactional Processing Database Systems whereas the snowflake and the star schema are great designs for Analytical Processing Systems and Warehouses but not for daily transactional Processing Systems. They are looking for an OLTP system than an OLAP System.

- **OLTP (On-line Transaction Processing)** is characterized by a large number of short on-line transactions (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). The main emphasis for OLTP systems is put on very fast query processing, maintaining data integrity in multi-access environments and an effectiveness measured by a number of transactions per second. In OLTP database there is detailed and current data, and schema used to store transactional databases is the entity model (usually 3NF).
- **OLAP (On-line Analytical Processing)** is characterized by a relatively low volume of transactions. Queries are often very complex and involve aggregations. For OLAP systems a response time is an effectiveness measure. OLAP applications are widely used by Data Mining techniques. In OLAP database there is aggregated, historical data, stored in multi-dimensional schemas (usually star schema).